# What to do when someone doesn't accept answer?

Tags: support

I answered a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420772/what-is-the-code-to-disable-open-file-under-menu-tab-in-firefox-userchrome-css/420831#420831) because I could. Questioner [acknowledges that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420772/what-is-the-code-to-disable-open-file-under-menu-tab-in-firefox-userchrome-css/420831#comment543884_420831) but makes additional points and is not accepting my answer. What to do?

Comment: **Stop caring about accepted answers!** A *wrong* but *accepted* answer does more harm than no accepted answer at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Why should I not care? Are you meaning the answer to original question is wrong?

Comment: I'm saying that there is no need to worry about accepted answers. If, at one point, the accepted answer becomes outdated and the asker doesn't change the accepted answer that is *worse* than the answer never getting accepted in the first place. Just stop worrying about it. See also [this Q&A](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5440/forcing-leavers-to-accept-an-answer/5443#5443)

Comment: So answers should be accepted only if they are "time-proof"? Your other link is about people who ask and don't return? Not applicable here? I think I will be more careful in future.

Comment: All I'm saying is that the accepted answer doesn't matter. There is no harm in *not* having an accepted answer - post score is just as good an indicator of answer usefulness.

Comment: unless you can somehow point a gun at his head :) let go

Comment: If OP accepts I get some rep. That is important to me if not to others. "Post score" whatever that is is another matter and may remain low if this Q&A is of no interest to others.

Comment: @Fischer, yes, I will let go but I don't feel good about it.

Comment: @DKBose [:)](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/107/227/tumblr_lgxpiaKYy91qa556so1_500.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [my question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8391/newbie-user-ask-and-go-away-forever)

The summary for this is as @FEichinger said:

> Stop caring about accepted answers! A wrong but accepted answer does
>   more harm than no accepted answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, don't care about **anything** that is not in your control, and the OP accepting your answers is one of them.

The best thing you can do, is write good answers, which will inturn get you upvotes! And yes, this matters- to you and to the site, as well since upvotes not only means the problem can be resolved but also, in most cases, that the answer is good- the method used to solve the problem is appreciable.